# Is Romans 1:27 referring to venereal disease?

Tags: romans, pauline-epistles

Paul writes:

Rom 1:27  and the men likewise gave up natural relations with women and were consumed with passion for one another, men committing shameless acts with men and receiving in themselves the due penalty for their error.

Does "in themselves" mean "in their bodies"? And is the "due penalty" refer to venereal diseases?

Comment: Although this ***may*** be what Paul intended, there is nothing in the text that can lead to an answer through hermeneutics, especially as heterosexual promiscuity can also lead to venereal diseases. Your question seems to be seeking an opinion.

Comment: @DickHarfield  Thanks, so do you have anything to contribute to help us understand what "in themselves" might mean?

Comment: @DickHarfield I wouldn't say this is seeking an opinion, although it could. Hermeneutics extends beyond "what does only this text say." It can extend to how else the author used the words, how other biblical writers used this or similar phrases, how non-biblical contemporaries used it, and lastly how non-biblical non-contemporaries used these words within the same origin language so that we might be able to glean information. Just because the question doesn't have an easy answer from within the single verse doesn't mean it's mere opinion as an only answer.

Comment: @MicahGafford I agree with your statement that hermeneutics extends beyond exegesis of the text. As far as I can see, no other biblical author uses ἀντιμισθίαν ἣν ἔδει such as to give a guide as to what Paul meant. This leaves me with my opinion that he may have meant a sexually transmitted disease - and this is probably the opinion of many others- but I can't see how to go from opinion to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dick Harfield mentioned, the text does not provide or lead toward an answer through hermeneutics. By exploring your second question regarding "due penalty," however, there are some verses to consider in order to hopefully bring better clarity to what you are seeking.

"Due penalty" can very well refer to venereal diseases. On a deeper level as well as keeping consistent to what the verses around verse 27 state, the "due penalty" suggests to be tied to sin: the nature of sin and God's judgment toward sin.

In verses 24, 26, and 28 we read not once, but thrice, that God gives man up to sin.

**"Therefore God also gave them up to uncleanness" -- vv. 24 (NKJV).**

**"For this reason God gave them up to vile passions" -- vv. 26 (NKJV).**

**" God gave them over to a debased mind, to do those things which are not fitting" -- vv. 28 (NKJV).**

These verses are certainly noteworthy because they reveal sin as unrighteousness before a righteous God Who will judge / penalize sin. With this framework in mind, here are two sources that may help you better understand the "due penalty" that is subject to those who will receive (it) "in themselves."

**@EnduringWord Bible Commentary**

> *e. Receiving in themselves the penalty of their error which was due*:
>   Paul speaks of a *penalty* for homosexual conduct; homosexuality has
>   within itself a penalty. This speaks of the generally self-destructive
>   nature of sin; it often carries within itself it’s own penalty.
>
> i. Sometimes it is the penalty of disease, which is the consequence of
>   violating nature’s order. Sometimes it is the penalty of rebellion,
>   resulting in spiritual emptiness and all it’s ramifications. In this
>   sense the term “gay” is wishful thinking. It sends a message that
>   there is something essentially happy and carefree about the homosexual
>   lifestyle – which there is not.
>
> f. Again, this “freedom” to disobey should be seen as God’s judgment,
>   not His kindness; those who engage in such acts are *receiving in
>   themselves the penalty of their error*.

https://enduringword.com/commentary/romans-1

**@The MacArthur Bible Commentary**

> **1:27 *receiving* in themselves the penalty.** Here, the law of sowing and reaping (Gal. 6:7, 8) takes effect, as
>   Paul refers to the self-destructive nature of this sin, of which AIDS
>   is one frightening evidence.

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted and accepted as answer. I do wish, though that someone had some exegetical explanation for the difference of the clause with "in themselves" as opposed to without those words. Also, is it only males who receive the penalty "in themselves"? There have only been 5 cases of lesbian sex passing AIDS. Is this true of other STDs? Might that be a clue? http://www.aidsmap.com/Female-to-female-sexual-transmission/page/1323529/

Comment: Happy to help! Thanks for the upvote, this was my first attempt to answer a question since I joined haha.

Comment: Let me send you a PM (private message) regarding your further questions and curiosity, since it seems like they will lead us to areas beyond heremeneutics.

Comment: I don't know how to PM here so if you can't figure it out, please ask for help on the "Meta" list. And welcome to the forum!

Comment: Same here - I also cannot figure out how to PM.

Comment: You did a good job with the writing and organizing of your thoughts, but I don't think your answer responds to the penalty of vd because: sources are biased; "which there is not" is an opinion; AIDS is not a homosexual disease -pregnant women, drug users, Charlie Sheen, etc get it. This response essentially implies that God gives vd to homosexual people. That's not in the text. Implying that "the penalty" is vd is prejudicial bias against homosexuals. Heterosexual Christians can get vd.

Comment: @Daisy: Good points, and I agree! Coming into this question, I kind of knew that I would have to insert (as you mentioned) some biases, opinions, assumptions, etc. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: @Daisy  I think the answer did a good job of relating the text to realities. I pointed out that I hoped for more explanation of why only males received the penalty. It appears that it is very easy for a woman to contract HIV from a man through his semen but much less likely that a man will "receive the penalty" from a woman. I expressed the tenuous idea that maybe the fact that sodomy spreads HIV more readily than "missionary" sex might be a plausible reason why Paul associates "receiving the penalty in themselves" to male-male. I'm here to learn by exploring - no agenda.

Comment: May I insert a fairly trivial issue here, relevant to this answer, but not the question. AIDS did not exist as a human disease at the time of Paul. For Macarthur BC even to give this generically as a "frightening evidence" demonstrates a lack of intellectual rigour ill-suited to a site like ours. ie gonorrhoea would have been less anachronistic, but of course less emotive.

Comment: @DickHarfield, Not only did it not exist; it originated from apes.

Comment: @DickHarfield  I know the verse is not about AIDS per se but VD, particularly a virus, does seem to fit the verse somewhat nicely. Do you have a better suggestion? I'm certainly open.

Comment: @WoundedEgo As now stated twice in my comments on the question, it is my opinion that he may have meant a sexually transmitted disease - but that is only an opinion. Incidentally Gee Sus cites a source that says another option is 'rebellion and spiritual emptiness', although I would say this is just as anachronistic for 1st century Greece as would AIDS be.

Comment: @DickHarfield  Another possibility is a sore butt! Unfortunately, Paul's not around for us to ask him. :-)

Comment: In many cases, we don't need to be able to ask the author, because there are enough clues in the text or in the context or in the way contemporaries use the same phrase - but that is not the case here. Of course, we know that homosexual sex was treated as normal in ancient Greece, whereas the Romans would have tended to frown on it. So, Paul probably has to remember where he is writing when saying things like this.

Comment: @Dick Harfield: Well said. Glad we do have the Holy Spirit to help and guide us as we process these such difficult texts!  I agree that it helps to regard the historical groups. To add, quoting from a commentator:

“The Christians of Rome were unpopular – reputed to be ‘enemies of the human race’ and credited with such vices as incest and cannibalism. In large numbers, then, they became the victims of the imperial malevolence – and it is this persecution of Christians under Nero that traditionally forms the setting for Paul’s martyrdom.” (Bruce)